# Is there a way to use an object constructor to create multiple HTML elements but with unique attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, object

Anyways, I think that I have been staring at code too long to be able to think straight, so any help would be appreciated. Below is my code that seems unnecessarily repetitive.

```
var P1actionContainer = document.createElement("div");
    P1actionContainer.setAttribute("id", "P1actionContainer");
    P1actionContainer.classList.add("actioncontainer");
    topbox.appendChild(P1actionContainer);

            // FOLD
        var P1fold = document.createElement("input");
            P1fold.setAttribute("id", "P1foldButton");
            P1fold.setAttribute("type", "button");
            P1fold.setAttribute("value", "FOLD");
            P1fold.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            //fold.addEventListener("click", stepTenFold);
            P1actionContainer.appendChild(P1fold);

            // CALL
        var P1call = document.createElement("input");
            P1call.setAttribute("id", "P1callButton");
            P1call.setAttribute("type", "button");
            P1call.setAttribute("value", "CALL");
            P1call.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            //call.addEventListener("click", stepTenCall);
            P1actionContainer.appendChild(P1call);

            // BET SLIDER
        var P1betSlider = document.createElement("input");
            P1betSlider.setAttribute("id", "P1betSlider");
            P1betSlider.setAttribute("type", "range");
            P1betSlider.setAttribute("value", "0");
            P1betSlider.setAttribute("min", blinds.L1B * 2);
            P1betSlider.setAttribute("max", P1.stack);
            P1betSlider.setAttribute("step", blinds.L1S);
            P1betSlider.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            P1betSlider.addEventListener("input", P1adjustBetDisplay);
            P1actionContainer.appendChild(P1betSlider);

            // BET DISPLAY
        var P1betSliderValue = document.getElementById("P1betSlider").value;
        var P1betDisplay = document.createElement("input");
            P1betDisplay.setAttribute("id", "P1betDisplay");
            P1betDisplay.setAttribute("type", "number");
            P1betDisplay.setAttribute("value", P1betSliderValue);
            P1betDisplay.setAttribute("min", blinds.L1B * 2)
            P1betDisplay.setAttribute("max", P1.stack);
            P1betDisplay.setAttribute("step", blinds.L1S)
            P1betDisplay.setAttribute("maxlength", 4);
            P1betDisplay.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            P1betDisplay.addEventListener("input", P1adjustBetSlider);
            P1actionContainer.appendChild(P1betDisplay);

            // BET
        var P1bet = document.createElement("input");
            P1bet.setAttribute("id", "betButton");
            P1bet.setAttribute("type", "button");
            P1bet.setAttribute("value", "RAISE");
            P1bet.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            //bet.addEventListener("click", stepTenBet);
            P1actionContainer.appendChild(P1bet);

var P2actionContainer = document.createElement("div");
    P2actionContainer.setAttribute("id", "P2actionContainer");
    P2actionContainer.classList.add("actioncontainer");
    botbox.appendChild(P2actionContainer);

            // FOLD
        var P2fold = document.createElement("input");
            P2fold.setAttribute("id", "P2foldButton");
            P2fold.setAttribute("type", "button");
            P2fold.setAttribute("value", "FOLD");
            P2fold.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            //fold.addEventListener("click", stepTenFold);
            P2actionContainer.appendChild(P2fold);

            // CALL
        var P2call = document.createElement("input");
            P2call.setAttribute("id", "P2callButton");
            P2call.setAttribute("type", "button");
            P2call.setAttribute("value", "CALL");
            P2call.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            //call.addEventListener("click", stepTenCall);
            P2actionContainer.appendChild(P2call);

            // BET SLIDER
        var P2betSlider = document.createElement("input");
            P2betSlider.setAttribute("id", "P2betSlider");
            P2betSlider.setAttribute("type", "range");
            P2betSlider.setAttribute("value", "0");
            P2betSlider.setAttribute("min", blinds.L1B * 2);
            P2betSlider.setAttribute("max", P2.stack);
            P2betSlider.setAttribute("step", blinds.L1S);
            P2betSlider.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            P2betSlider.addEventListener("input", P2adjustBetDisplay);
            P2actionContainer.appendChild(P2betSlider);

            // BET DISPLAY
        var P2betSliderValue = document.getElementById("P2betSlider").value;
        var P2betDisplay = document.createElement("input");
            P2betDisplay.setAttribute("id", "P2betDisplay");
            P2betDisplay.setAttribute("type", "number");
            P2betDisplay.setAttribute("value", P2betSliderValue);
            P2betDisplay.setAttribute("min", blinds.L1B * 2)
            P2betDisplay.setAttribute("max", P2.stack);
            P2betDisplay.setAttribute("step", blinds.L1S)
            P2betDisplay.setAttribute("maxlength", 4);
            P2betDisplay.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            P2betDisplay.addEventListener("input", P2adjustBetSlider);
            P2actionContainer.appendChild(P2betDisplay);

            // BET
        var P2bet = document.createElement("input");
            P2bet.setAttribute("id", "betButton");
            P2bet.setAttribute("type", "button");
            P2bet.setAttribute("value", "RAISE");
            P2bet.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
            //bet.addEventListener("click", stepTenBet);
            P2actionContainer.appendChild(P2bet);
```

**So, is there a way to use an object constructor to create these particular elements?**

I've tried the code below and similar variations of it--one of which used properties in addition to values instead of just statements, as is the case below.

```
var createInput = function(elementName, a, v, aa, vv, aaa, vvv)
{
    elementName = document.createElement("input");
    elementName.setAttribute(a, v);
    elementName.setAttribute(aa, vv);
    elementName.setAttribute(aaa, vvv);
};

var P1fold = new createInput("P1fold", "id", "P1foldButton", "type", "button", "value", "FOLD");

    P1fold.classList.add("...");
```

However, I was getting an error to the effect of "Cannot add class to undefined".

Comment: Creating DOM elements is a thing one can certainly do in a constructor, but the two concepts don't have anything in particular in common with each other. Constructors are used in JavaScript to create particular kinds of *JavaScript* elements; it doesn't have anything to do with the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy        Particular kinds of JS elements such as Object.prototypes? Or to which elements are you referring? But my code interacts with the DOM and its nodes. In fact, the code above creates HTML elements and inserts them into the DOM. So is there a way to use an object constructor to create unique HTML elements with unique attributes?

Comment: Sorry; I should have used the word "objects" - JavaScript *objects* is what I meant.

Comment: And the answer to that question in your comment is "not really". DOM elements are part of the native environment of the JavaScript runtime in a browser, but they're *not* JavaScript and they're not part of the language proper.

Comment: @Pointy        So the code above, although verbose, isn't exactly unnecessarily verbose?

Comment: Well another approach is to use a tool like jQuery to manage some of the mess, or even more different, a template tool to create HTML and then use other DOM APIs to build DOM elements (especially the `innerHTML` API).

Comment: Oh, also, even with code like yours, you don't need to use `.setAttribute()` to set things like "id", "type", "value", etc - those are exposed as properties on the DOM element objects, so you can just write `P1fold.id = "whatever";`. You only need `.setAttribute()` when the attribute is not one that's expected for the given node type.

Comment: @Pointy        That's actually what I was using when I first began learning "JS" a while ago, the jQuery library. However, I had only recently started programming again, and I had decided at that time to learn and perfect JavaScript itself since it's the foundation of that library and utilized for other technologies. What I'm doing is creating poker software as an exercise to learn and develop my knowledge about JavaScript. So like setAttribute would be used for setting, say, the opacity of an HTML element? Or which attributes "aren't expected for [a] given node type"? Thanks for the info, btw

Comment: An example would be the "name" attribute. An `<input>` element will have "name" as an object property, but a `<div>` would not because in HTML a "name" attribute doesn't mean anything on a `<div>`. Both kinds of elements can have an "id", or a "style", or a "title", and those can be accessed directly as properties on the DOM nodes. In any case, `.setAttribute()` is a facility provided by the browser environment; it's not part of JavaScript *per se*.

Comment: @              Fascinating. So you wouldn't be able to set `name` for an `<input>` element by typing this: `element.name = "theName"`?

Comment: No, you would be able to do it for an `<input>` element and have the value work as the "name" attribute (to the DOM mechanisms, like form posting). You can do it for the `<div>` node too, but it won't have any effect on stuff the browser does with/for the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy        So I was trouble-shooting something earlier, and changed an `element.id = "whatever"` to `element.name = "whatever"` and not only was it acceptable but it also didn't seem to have any effect at all on the functionality of the given element or its corresponding JS. Sorry, I'm struggling to understand your last reply.

Answer (score 0):

The first tools in code re-use are functions and parameters.  When only one or two things change in your code pile, pull them out as parameters and turn the repetitive bits in functions.  This should get you started...

```
function makeContainer(idPrefix, doc)
{
   var container = doc.createElement('div');
   container.setAttribute('id', idPrefix + 'container');
   container.classList.add("actioncontainer");
   //code to call functions to create buttons, etc.
   container.appendChild(makeButton(idPrefix, 'Call', doc));
   container.appendChild(makeButton(idPrefix, 'Bet', doc));
   //etc...
   return container; 
}

function makeButton(idPrefix, value, doc)
{

   var button = doc.createElement('input');
   button.setAttribute('id', idPrefix + value + 'button');
   button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
   button.setAttribute('value', value);
   button.classList.add("actionbuttonmargins");
   return button;
}
//Other functions for sliders, etc.

topbox.appendChild(makeContainer('p1', document));
topbox.appendChild(makeContainer('p2', document));
```

Comment: I've already tried the code below and variations of it (one of which used properties in addition to values instead of just statements as is the case below).

var createInput = function(elementName, a, v, aa, vv, aaa, vvv)
{
 elementName = document.createElement("input");
 elementName.setAttribute(a, v);
 elementName.setAttribute(aa, vv);
 elementName.setAttribute(aaa, vvv);
};

var P1fold = new createInput("P1fold", "id", "P1foldButton", "type", "button", "value", "FOLD");

P1fold.classList.add("...");

Comment: However, I was getting an error to the effect of "Cannot add class to undefined".

I'm not sure how your block of code differs at all from mine? How would yours be effective? Can you achieve the effect I'm looking for and post it somewhere? @dbugger